# iterating through array, android dev

Tags: java, android, arrays, iteration

I have a question I have been holding off for about a week, because I thought I can figure it out but I can't!! lol.

Well, I have created an int array just as the following.

```
int[] a = new int[11];
    a[0] = 15;
    a[1] = 16
    a[2] = 17;
    a[3] = 18;
    a[4] = 19;
    a[5] = 20;
    a[6] = 21;
    a[7] = 22;
    a[8] = 23;
    a[9] = 24;
    a[10] = 25;
```

what I want is to get user to input a value from 1 thru 10. I want to be able to match their input with the index of the array, then finally return the value. So, if the user inputs 7, then 22 will be returned, or if user input is 4, then 19 is returned.

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: If the user inputs a number between 1 and 10, Why does your array have 11 elements?

Comment: well the list is much longer I would like to know how to increment through the array till I find the matching index and return the value.

Comment: @ JB Nizet because [0] is also included

Answer (score 2):

if user input is `int input`, you obtain the value with `a[input]`

Is this the answer to your question? Or do you wonder where to get the input from? In that case, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

write it as a method for more convenience:

```
public int checkArray(int val){
    int[] a = new int[11];
    a[0] = 15;
    a[1] = 16;
    a[2] = 17;
    a[3] = 18;
    a[4] = 19;
    a[5] = 20;
    a[6] = 21;
    a[7] = 22;
    a[8] = 23;
    a[9] = 24;
    a[10] = 25;

    return a[val];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop...

```
for(int i = 0;i=userinput;i++)
{
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires no iteration.

You need to create a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and just `return a[scanner.nextInt()];` [where `scanner` is the initialized `Scanner`].

Note the above is not safe, it might invoke `IndexOutOfBoundException` if the user will insert `100` for example.